# Is there any way to send push notifications to only specific app version?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase to send the push notification to user devices.
I want to send the push notifications to only to devices which have specific app version.

Is there any way to send push notification from server programmatically not using firebase console. So far I am not storing the user's app version in the server database.

Comment: Without having the app-version on you server DB, or not checking app-version on your app when receiving it you will not be able to filter the notification to only those with a certain app-version

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54446622/209103) to the question I linked for an example of how to implement this.